# mysql multiple case on same column

Tags: mysql

Learner here.

Have tried looking for answer on the web, but did not find any.
This is a created scenario. The actual one is a bit more complex.

A table with 3 columns, id, color and quantity. Sample data is:

| id | color | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | 3 |
| 1 | Blue | 4 |
| 1 | Yellow | 3 |
| 1 | Red | 4 |
| 1 | Blue | 2 |

Running following query:

```
SELECT
  id,
  CASE
    WHEN color = 'Red' THEN SUM(quantity)
    ELSE 0
  END AS red_quantity,
  CASE
    WHEN color = 'Yellow' THEN SUM(quantity)
    ELSE 0
  END AS yellow_quantity,
  CASE
    WHEN color = 'Blue' then SUM(quantity)
    ELSE 0
  END AS blue_quantity
FROM
  test
```

Expected result is a single row with 4 columns as follows:

| id | red_quantity | yellow_quantity | blue_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 3 | 6 |

Instead getting as:

| id | red_quantity | yellow_quantity | blue_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | 0 | 0 |

As I understand, this is happening due to group by.
But what is the alternative, preferably - without discarding case?

Appreciate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just return the quantity from the case, and wrap the case in a SUM, instead of trying to sum within the case.

```
SELECT id,
    SUM(case when color='Red' then quantity else 0 end) as red_quantity,
    SUM(case when color='Yellow' then quantity else 0 end) as yellow_quantity,
    SUM(case when color='Blue' then quantity else 0 end) as blue_quantity
from test group by id
```

Your original query was saying, if the color of the row in question is red then sum all of the quantities.
Wrapping the SUM around the case means the SUM will only get the value from the CASE - so a non-zero if the row is the correct color.

*Adding further clarification as requested.*

The reason your query doesn't work is down to how MySQL processes the query internally.
Effectively, it's grouping the records BEFORE it evaluates your CASE statements, because it doesn't "see" that you want an aggregation.

So if MySQL groups your records by ID *first*, then you get one record with a non-deterministic color.

```
1 | red
```

If you run your CASE statements on this record, you'll get 1-16-0-0

The non-deterministic color could have quite easily been any of others, depending on how MySQL orders the records internally. So you could run your query many times and get different results (1-0-16-0 or 1-0-0-16).

Comment: The problem gets solved by the solution. But need clarification for understanding how things work. As I understand from your answer, in my original query, since all the three cases are true, each case should have returned total quantity as resp_color_quantity and the result should have been 1--16--16--16. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `case` should be the argument to the `sum()`:

```
SELECT id,
       sum(case when color = 'Red' then quantity else 0 end) as red_quantity,
       sum(case when color = 'Yellow' then quantity else 0 end) as yellow_quantity,
       sum(case when color = 'Blue' then quantit) else 0 end) as blue_quantity
from test
group by id
```